# Get all span inside Hidden field using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I m new to Jquery. I'm having hidden variable which contains all span tag inside it. Can any tell me how to access all span inside hidden field value.

For example: I'm having 3 span inside hidden field. I need to get all span inside hidden field as array of Span .

I tried this it is not working

```
$('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%> span').each(function() {

            var $span = $(this);
            var spanTxt = $span.html();  
            // do something with the above

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
$('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%> span').each(function() {
        var $span = $(this);
        var spanTxt = $span.text();  
        // do something with the above

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a typo, but make sure you're using `$()` to wrap your selectors and not just `()`. So

```
$('#<%=lblStatus.ClientID%> span').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    var spanTxt = $span.html();  
    // do something with the above
    });
```